# Most efficient method for calculating factorial of very large numbers

Tags: c, factorial

I am aware of the algorithm which uses school mathematics for calculating factorial for very large numbers, where we keep storing digits, multiply the next number with each digit stored, keep updating the digits, handle carries, etc.

Now I want to ask whether the implementation of this algorithm is most efficient using Singly Linked Lists
or using Doubly Linked Lists.

If we use singly-linked lists and store the digits of the number in reverse order, like this

```
123456
```

is stored as

```
6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

in the linked list. It is very easy to keep calculating the factorial using this approach, but when it comes to printing the result, we would have to iterate the list many times (O(n^2)) as we cant traverse backward in a singly linked list.

So should we use a doubly-linked list to get better efficiency both in terms of space and time complexity?
I mean, is it worth doing.

Comment: I think arrays should be used.

Comment: "Most efficient" and "linked list" cannot occur in the same sentence, it's against the law.

Comment: If you are allowed to modify the list pointers, a singly linked list can be reversed in O(n) time.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I don't want to discuss absolute merits of the linked answers, but none of them is applicable to this question. In this problem, an array is going to be more efficient than a linked list.

Comment: Storing individual digits is suboptimal as well. And at some point it will start to end with more and more zeros, which can be exploited too. What is "very large" anyway?

Comment: Sometimes you don't actually *need* those very large factorials, for example when computing such as a Taylor series you can build on the previous term.

Comment: I would go for an array, normally, because it is a good choice for bigints and also for all of the algorithms I know to compute a factorial (linear, recursive, binary splitting, or Borwein's trick with or without Schönhage's extension). My problem is, that your description of the algorithm you want to use is a bit too ambiguous for me. Would you mind to explain it with a bit more details?